# How to define a function that is Listable for some but not all arguments?

Tags: function-construction, attributes

I want to define a function `f[x,y]` that is `Listable` for only the first argument, not the second. If we use `SetAttributes[f, Listable]`, then `f` will be "Listable" for all arguments. For example, we define

```
f[x_, y_] := {x, y}
SetAttributes[f, Listable]

f[{1, 2, 3}, y]  (* -> {{1, y}, {2, y}, {3, y}} *)
f[{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}]  (* -> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}} *)
```

If `f` is `Listable` for only the first variable, I expect

```
f[{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}]
(* -> {{1, {a, b, c}}, {2, {a, b, c}}, {3, {a, b, c}}} *)
```

Namely, no matter what `y` is, I want to always get

```
f[{1, 2, 3}, y]  (* -> {{1, y}, {2, y}, {3, y}} *)
```

Similar to `HoldAll`, `HoldFirst`, `HoldRest`, etc, I think it is natural to have something like `ListableAll`, `ListableFirst`, `ListableRest`, etc. I cannot understand why it is not a built-in capability of *Mathematica*. Is there a way to define a function that is `Listable` for some but not all variables?

Comment: I have extensively discussed this problem in my book, [here](http://mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node401.html) and also [here](http://mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node425.html), where you will find several possible solutions to it.

Comment: Clearly `Listable` satisfies `ListableAll`, so you don't anything new for that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about

```
f[x_List, y_] := f[#, y] & /@ x
f[x_, y_] := {x, y}
```

With this definition

```
f[{1, 2, 3}, y]
```

> `{{1, y}, {2, y}, {3, y}}`

and

```
f[{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}]
```

> `{{1, {a, b, c}}, {2, {a, b, c}}, {3, {a, b, c}}}`

Answer (score 7):

You can directly use your definition as follows:

```
ReleaseHold@f[{1, 2, 3}, Hold@{a, b, c}]

(*{{1, {a, b, c}}, {2, {a, b, c}}, {3, {a, b, c}}}*)
```

Comment: `f[{1, 2, 3}, Defer[{a, b, c}]]` works too.

Comment: @Coolwater, It works but it will stay in the output,. `f[{1, 2, 3}, HoldForm[{a, b, c}]]` works also but it will stay in the output too. Check this: `f[{1, 2, 3}, Defer[{1+1, b, c}]]` and compare it with `ReleaseHold@f[{1, 2, 3}, Hold@{1+1, b, c}]`

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `Thread`

```
Thread[List[Range@3, y]]
```

> {{1, y}, {2, y}, {3, y}}

```
Thread[List[Range@3, Sequence[x, y]]]
```

> {{1, x, y}, {2, x, y}, {3, x, y}}